# No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type `string` from content with media type `text/html`

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

`HttpClient`:

```
public string BridgeSP(long SPId)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        ReadConfig();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", GenerateAuthenticationToken());
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //HTTP POST
        var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(ApiActionName + "/" + SPId, SPId);
        responseTask.Wait();

        var result = responseTask.Result;
        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
        readTask.Wait();
        response = result.StatusCode + "|" + readTask.Result;
    }
    return response;
}
```

`WebApi`:

```
[BasicAuthenticationAttribute]
[ActionName("BridgeSP")]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(long SPId)
{
    try
    {
        Utility.QBUpdateVendor(SPId);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "SP Bridged Successful ");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

WebApiConfig.cs:

```
config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Why this error thrown while calling web api?

Comment: maybe this could be useful ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184427/no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-text-html

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSFT documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh944521(v=vs.118).aspx) you should send the uri without the variable SPId

In this line:

```
var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(ApiActionName + "/" + SPId, SPId);
```

you send content with `SPId` to the url "...ApiActionName/SPId", however, should use something like this:

```
var response = httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(String.Format("{0}/{1}", controller, action), request).Result;
```

and finally, You should call response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() to make sure the response indicates success (typically 200 OK). If it's not the case, it will raise an exception.

And finally and an attribute to method to api post `[Route("BridgeSP/{SPId}")]`

Or maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25184427/no-mediatypeformatter-is-available-text-html) could help you

Answer (score 0):

> Why this error thrown while calling web api?

I bet your request fails with 404 HTTP error because of misconfigured routing (see below). Response contains html payload with error description. But on the client side you don't check http error code and try to deserialize the response body as it contains JSON string. That's why you get "No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type `string` from content with media type `text/html`" error.

You have to make several fixes in your code to avoid that.

First of all, youre trying to pass `SPId` in both URL and request body. Although it is possible, but it's better to avoid such redundancy. You should choose whether you want to pass this id in the URL or in the body. For single numeric parameter which identifies a resource, passing in the URL is prefered because it complies with REST principles. Here is appropriate change on the client:

`var responseTask = client.PostAsync(ApiActionName + "/" + SPId, null);`

Passing `null` in `content` parameter of `PostAsync` will send POST request with 
no body.

You should also ajust your server part. You have to specify routing so that value for `SPId` could be extracted from the request URL:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("BridgeSP/{SPId}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(long SPId)
{
    //  ...
```

Now your action could be accessed via `http://localhost/BridgeSP/123` URL. If you want to keep controller name in the URL, you should also set `Route` attribute for the controller. Check this article about [attribute routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) for more details.

Then in the client you should check response code before deserializing the body. This will prevent you from getting odd exception that you asked about. The easiest way is to call `HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` method that will throw if request finished with some HTTP error.

Here is adjusted client code:

```
public string BridgeSP(long SPId)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {

        ReadConfig();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", GenerateAuthenticationToken());
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //HTTP POST
        var responseTask = client.PostAsync(ApiActionName + "/" + SPId, null);
        var result = responseTask.Result;
        //  This will throw if request finished with some HTTP error
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>();
        readTask.Wait();
        response = result.StatusCode + "|" + readTask.Result;
    }
    return response;
}
```

Make sure that correct API URL is configured on the client side (`"/BridgeSP" + "/" + SPId`).